# How to create a method parameter object with ReSharper in a few seconds?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, refactoring, resharper, parameter-object

Is it possible to select all the parameters of a method and ask ReSharper to create a class from those parameters as a "method parameter object?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ReSharper supports the command [Extract Class From Parameters](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Refactoring/extractclassfromparameters.html):

> The Extract Class From Parameters
>   refactoring allows you to quickly
>   create a new class or structure using
>   (some of) the parameters of a given
>   method. ReSharper analyses the
>   selected method and detects the
>   variables that can be converted into
>   members. After extraction, the new
>   class is created with the necessary
>   fields generated from the selected
>   method's parameters.

To invoke it:

1. Place the cursor on the method with
   the parameters you want to generate a class for
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
3. Select '**Extract Class From
   Parameters**'
4. Do any additional configuration in the dialog box.

Comment: That's awesome ... I didn't know you could do that!

Answer (score 4):

In ReSharper 2018.1, the sequence is now:

1. Place the cursor on the method name.
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
3. Select *Transform Parameters*
4. Change the default class name from *InClassName* to something appropriate.
5. Click *Next* (which should really be OK because it immediately makes the change)